# Extract data form php/curl parsing

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I have a html document to parse with curl.

This is the part where i'm trying to extract particular data :

```
    <table align="center"><td class="normal" valign="top">
      <b>Name :</b> John<br />
      <b>Alias :</b> Jo<br />
      <b>Town :</b> Miami<br />
    </td></table>
```

I would like to extract "John", i try it like that :

```
foreach($page->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table) {
    if ($table->getAttribute('align') == "center") {

    preg_match('#<b>Name :</b> (.+)<br />#isU', $table, $matches);
    echo $matches;

    }
}
```

I tried to put two "markers" ('`<b>Name :</b>`' and '`<br />`'), but i have nothing in return, what's wrong ?

I have to do that on others page, structure is the same.

Comment: Why you use PHP for this? Why don't you use Jquery?

Comment: i can't use js, this script run with a crontab directly on a server (when it's ready, echo is for test).

Comment: Change your pattern to this `<b>Name :<\/b> (.+)<br \/>`

Comment: are you sure ? it's return nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex to match the word `John`,

```
<b>Name\s*:<\/b>\s+\K[^<>]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wE4fI1/8)